# How to Keep Object on Top Layer When Selecting an another Object in Fabric.js Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I'm working on a project where I'm using the Fabric.js library to create a canvas with text and images. I have a requirement where I want to ensure that the text always remains on the top layer, even when I'm actively selecting an image to upload.

I've implemented the functionality to upload images and add text to the canvas. However, when I select an image, the image seems to overlay the text, which is not the behavior I desire. Instead, I want the text to remain on the top layer regardless of whether an image is being selected or not.

I've tried using the following methods to manage layering:

```
canvas.sendBackwards(myObject)
canvas.sendToBack(myObject)
canvas.bringForward(myObject)
canvas.bringToFront(myObject)
```

However, I haven't been able to achieve the desired behavior. The text still gets obscured by the image during the image upload process.

```js
   <script>
      // Initialize Firebase with your own config
      const firebaseConfig = {//
      };

      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      const storage = firebase.storage();
      const firestore = firebase.firestore();

      // Update the submit button click event handler
      document
        .getElementById("submit-button")
        .addEventListener("click", async () => {
          const imageFilename = document.getElementById("image-filename").value;

          // Convert the canvas to a PNG data URL
          const pngDataURL = canvas.toDataURL({ format: "png", multiplier: 3 }); // Adjust multiplier as needed for higher resolution

          // Convert the data URL to a Blob
          const pngBlob = await (await fetch(pngDataURL)).blob();

          // Create a reference to Firebase storage
          const storageRef = storage.ref();

          // Define the path for the uploaded PNG
          const pngPath = `designs/${imageFilename}.png`;

          // Upload PNG to Firebase storage
          const pngUploadTask = storageRef.child(pngPath).put(pngBlob);

          pngUploadTask.on(
            "state_changed",
            (snapshot) => {
              // Handle upload progress if needed
              const progress =
                (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
              console.log(`Upload progress: ${progress}%`);
            },
            (error) => {
              // Handle errors
              console.error("Upload error:", error);
            },
            async () => {
              // Get the download URL of the uploaded PNG
              const downloadURL =
                await pngUploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
              console.log("PNG download URL:", downloadURL);

              const designRef = firestore.collection("designs").doc();
              const timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();

              await designRef.set({
                filename: imageFilename,
                url: downloadURL,
                timestamp: timestamp,
                completed: false,
              });

              // Show a success message
              window.location.href = "thank_you.html";

              // Clear the filename input field
              document.getElementById("image-filename").value = "";
            }
          );
        });

      const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("spacebar-canvas");

      // Load the sample SVG background
      fabric.loadSVGFromURL("sample.svg", function (objects, options) {
        const svg = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
        svg.scaleToWidth(canvas.width);
        svg.scaleToHeight(canvas.height);
        canvas.setBackgroundImage(svg, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
      });

      document
        .getElementById("image-upload")
        .addEventListener("change", handleImageUpload);
      document
        .getElementById("image-upload-2")
        .addEventListener("change", handleImageUpload);
      document
        .getElementById("image-upload-3")
        .addEventListener("change", handleImageUpload);

      document
        .getElementById("text-input")
        .addEventListener("input", updateText);
      document
        .getElementById("font-family")
        .addEventListener("change", updateText);
      document
        .getElementById("font-weight")
        .addEventListener("change", updateText);
      document.getElementById("italic").addEventListener("change", updateText);
      document
        .getElementById("text-color")
        .addEventListener("input", updateTextColor);

      document
        .getElementById("shape-color")
        .addEventListener("input", updateShapeColor);
      document
        .getElementById("small-shape-color")
        .addEventListener("input", updateSmallShapeColor);

      function handleImageUpload(e) {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        if (file) {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function (event) {
            const imageUrl = event.target.result;
            fabric.Image.fromURL(imageUrl, function (img) {
              img.scaleToWidth(40); // Adjust the width
              img.set({ left: 100, top: 10 }); // Adjust the initial position
              canvas.add(img);
              canvas.sendToBack(img); // Send the image to the back
              canvas.renderAll();
            });
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
      }

      // Add an event listener to the text input to select the text object when focused
      document
        .getElementById("text-input")
        .addEventListener("focus", selectTextObject);

      function selectTextObject() {
        const textObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
        if (textObject && textObject.type === "text") {
          canvas.setActiveObject(textObject);
          canvas.renderAll();
        }
      }

      // Update the text input event listeners
      document
        .getElementById("text-input")
        .addEventListener("input", updateText);
      document
        .getElementById("font-family")
        .addEventListener("change", updateText);
      document
        .getElementById("font-weight")
        .addEventListener("change", updateText);
      document.getElementById("italic").addEventListener("change", updateText);
      document
        .getElementById("text-color")
        .addEventListener("input", updateTextColor);

      // Update the updateText function
      function updateText() {
        const text = document.getElementById("text-input").value;
        const fontFamily = document.getElementById("font-family").value;
        const fontWeight = document.getElementById("font-weight").value;
        const isItalic = document.getElementById("italic").checked;
        const textColor = document.getElementById("text-color").value;

        // Remove existing text object before adding a new one
        canvas.forEachObject(function (obj) {
          if (obj.type === "text") {
            canvas.remove(obj);
          }
        });

        if (text) {
          const textObject = new fabric.Text(text, {
            left: canvas.width / 2,
            top: canvas.height / 2,
            fontSize: 18,
            fontFamily: fontFamily,
            fontWeight: fontWeight,
            fontStyle: isItalic ? "italic" : "normal",
            fill: textColor,
            originX: "center",
            originY: "center",
          });

          canvas.add(textObject);
          canvas.sendToFront(textObject); // Bring the text to the front
          canvas.renderAll();
        }
      }

      function updateShapeColor() {
        const shape = canvas
          .getObjects()
          .find((obj) => obj.type === "rect" && obj.name === "bgRect");
        if (shape) {
          shape.set({ fill: document.getElementById("shape-color").value });
          shape.visible = true; // Make the large rectangle visible
          canvas.renderAll();
        }
      }

      function updateSmallShapeColor() {
        const shape = canvas
          .getObjects()
          .find((obj) => obj.type === "rect" && obj.name === "centerRect");
        if (shape) {
          shape.set({
            fill: document.getElementById("small-shape-color").value,
          });
          shape.visible = true; // Make the small rectangle visible
          canvas.renderAll();
        }
      }

      function updateTextColor() {
        const textObject = canvas
          .getObjects()
          .find((obj) => obj.type === "text");
        if (textObject) {
          textObject.set({ fill: document.getElementById("text-color").value });
          canvas.renderAll();
        }
      }

      // Add a larger rectangle shape (background)
      const bgRect = new fabric.Rect({
        width: canvas.width,
        height: canvas.height,
        fill: "#000000",
        name: "bgRect", // Add a name to distinguish it
        selectable: false,
        visible: false, // Initially hidden
      });
      canvas.add(bgRect);

      // Add a smaller rectangle shape (centered)
      const centerRect = new fabric.Rect({
        width: 565, // Adjust the width
        height: 70, // Adjust the height
        fill: "#FF0000", // Initial color
        name: "centerRect", // Add a name to distinguish it
        left: canvas.width / 2,
        top: canvas.height / 2,
        originX: "center",
        originY: "center",
        selectable: false,
        visible: false, // Initially hidden
      });
      canvas.add(centerRect);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this? The code below is a setting that keeps the layer even when an object is selected.

```
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("spacebar-canvas", {
    preserveObjectStacking: true
});
```